# Change entitlements for iOS application built by different development team?

Tags: ios, xcode, target, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

My company has recently purchased an application that is currently on the app store under the previous company's name.

Because they enabled iCloud in their developer settings, we were unable to transfer ownership of the app directly to us, and instead, must manually get the source code from them.

We have received their code, however we cannot build the project in XCode because there are apparently entitlements missing that belonged to the old company in certain targets in the application.

From what I understand, the entitlement model is outdated and has been replaced in the new Versions of XCode. I have tried to set the developer team to our own company's team and enabled "Automatically manage signing"in the XCode Target settings, but this did not fix the issue.

At build I get this error (among a few others):

`error: The file “theProjectDependency.entitlements” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.`

How do I replace their project dependency entitlements with our own?

Comment: Does the file "theProjectDependency.entitlements" does exists in the project? Can you see it in the files hierarchy?